# Getting a "can't stat" error on build when trying to build a docker container within a Jenkins pipeline, but why?

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a Docker container by using a Dockerfile as a step in Jenkins 2.0 pipeline and the plugin Docker Pipeline Plugin.

I've created a Dockerfile which looks like so:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        file \
        aapt \
        lib32z1 \
        make \
        gcc-4.9-base \
        libgcc1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

"openjdk:8-jdk" is a valid openjdk8 image from Docker HUB.

Here's the relevant portion of the pipeline script (which has been edited for troubleshooting matters):

```
stage ('Compilation within Docker') {
        java = docker.build 'openjdk8:android'
        java.inside("-e GRADLE_USER_HOME=${GRADLE_USER_HOME} -e ANDROID_HOME=${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/android-sdk-linux" ) {
            withCredentials([ // Use Jenkins credentials ID of artifactory
                [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: artifactory_creds, usernameVariable: 'A_USER', passwordVariable: 'A_PASS'],
            ]){
                sh """
                echo "OK!"
                exit 0
                """
```

"openjdk8:android" is the name I chose for the image and is not official in any way.

For some reason when I run the build it fails with the following error:

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ docker build -t openjdk8:android .
Error checking context: 'can't stat '/mnt/storage/jenkins/jobs/product_android_build/workspace/company/build/generated/source/r/production/release/com''.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

The builds are obviously being run as the jenkins user but when I log into the Jenkins server and browse to the path mentioned in the error (`/mnt/storage/jenkins/jobs/product_android_build/workspace/company/build/generated/source/r/production/release/com`) I see that the owner of this folder is root.

I've tried `chown -R jenkins.jenkins folder` but after the next run root is back the owner of the folder (as fits the "generated" folder name in the path).

Any chance how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested... Deleting workspace directory from the job's directory on the Jenkins server fixed the problem.